Visualization of ranking models based on time executions
I'm working on reproducing the following plot for my own case:

so, let's say I already have my results ready and in the form of data frames as below:
import pandas as pd

# Data
data1 = {
    'Models': ['LinearRegression', 'Random Forest', 'XGBoost', 'MLPRegressor', 'SVR', 'CatBoostRegressor', 'LGBMRegressor'],
    'MAE': [4.906, 2.739, 2.826, 5.234, 5.061, 2.454, 2.76]
    'Runtime [ms]': [0:00:43.387145, 0:28:11.761681, 0:03:58.883474, 0:01:44.252276 , 0:04:52.754769, 0:19:36.925169, 0:04:51.223103]
}
data2 = {
    'Models': ['LinearRegression', 'Random Forest', 'XGBoost', 'MLPRegressor', 'SVR', 'CatBoostRegressor', 'LGBMRegressor'],
    'MAE': [4.575, 2.345, 2.129, 4.414, 4.353, 2.281, 2.511]
    'Runtime [ms]': [0:00:45.055854, 0:10:55.468473, 0:01:01.575033 , 0:00:31.231719 , 0:02:12.258870, 0:08:16.526615 , 0:15:25.084937]
}
data3 = {
    'Models': ['LinearRegression', 'Random Forest', 'XGBoost', 'MLPRegressor', 'SVR', 'CatBoostRegressor', 'LGBMRegressor'],
    'MAE': [4.575, 2.345, 2.129, 4.414, 4.353, 2.281, 2.511]
    'Runtime [ms]': [0:00:40.055854, 0:11:55.468473, 0:01:03.575033 , 0:00:29.231719 , 0:02:02.258870, 0:07:16.526615 , 0:13:25.084937]
}


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)

So now I can calculate the ranking by computing absolute\relative frequencies in the final ranked table in the expected output.
and get something like this to rank top models, but I will lose Runtime [ms]:
Top models(sorted)                                count   freq(%)
LinearRegression,MLPRegressor,SVR,LGBMRegresso...   2   66.666667
MLPRegressor,SVR,LinearRegression,XGBoost,LGBM...   1   33.333333

How can I get close to this plot?

I could have managed to find a good solution:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

# Data
data1 = {
    'Models': ['LinearRegression', 'Random Forest', 'XGBoost', 'MLPRegressor', 'SVR', 'CatBoostRegressor', 'LGBMRegressor'],
    'MAE': [4.906, 2.739, 2.826, 5.234, 5.061, 2.454, 2.76],
    'Runtime [ms]': ['0:00:43.387145', '0:28:11.761681', '0:03:58.883474', '0:01:44.252276', 
                     '0:04:52.754769', '0:19:36.925169', '0:04:51.223103']
}
data2 = {
    'Models': ['LinearRegression', 'Random Forest', 'XGBoost', 'MLPRegressor', 'SVR', 'CatBoostRegressor', 'LGBMRegressor'],
    'MAE': [4.575, 2.345, 2.129, 4.414, 4.353, 2.281, 2.511],
    'Runtime [ms]': ['0:00:45.055854', '0:10:55.468473', '0:01:01.575033', '0:00:31.231719', 
                     '0:02:12.258870', '0:08:16.526615', '0:15:25.084937']
}
data3 = {
    'Models': ['LinearRegression', 'Random Forest', 'XGBoost', 'MLPRegressor', 'SVR', 'CatBoostRegressor', 'LGBMRegressor'],
    'MAE': [4.575, 2.345, 2.129, 4.414, 4.353, 2.281, 2.511],
    'Runtime [ms]': ['0:00:40.055854', '0:11:55.468473', '0:01:03.575033', '0:00:29.231719', 
                     '0:02:02.258870', '0:07:16.526615', '0:13:25.084937']
}

# Convert data to DataFrames
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)

# Function to process DataFrame: calculate runtime in seconds and ranks
def process_df(df):
    df['Runtime [s]'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Runtime [ms]']).dt.total_seconds()
    df['Rank'] = df['MAE'].rank()  # Rank models based on MAE (lower is better)
    return df

df1 = process_df(df1)
df2 = process_df(df2)
df3 = process_df(df3)

# Combine all data
combined = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])

# Compute average rank and runtime for each model
agg_df = combined.groupby('Models', as_index=False).agg({
    'Rank': 'mean',
    'Runtime [s]': 'mean'
})

# Calculate frequencies for top N models in each DataFrame
top_n = 3
top_models = pd.concat([
    df1.nsmallest(top_n, 'MAE')['Models'],
    df2.nsmallest(top_n, 'MAE')['Models'],
    df3.nsmallest(top_n, 'MAE')['Models']
])

# Add absolute frequencies to agg_df
agg_df['Frequency'] = agg_df['Models'].map(top_models.value_counts()).fillna(0)
agg_df['Circle_Size'] = agg_df['Frequency'] * 300  # Scale circle sizes

# Identify optimal model (lowest rank and runtime)
optimal_model = agg_df.loc[agg_df['Rank'] == agg_df['Rank'].min()]

# Tree-based models
tree_based_models = ['Random Forest', 'XGBoost', 'CatBoostRegressor', 'LGBMRegressor']

# Visualization
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

# Scatter plot with sizes based on frequencies
for _, row in agg_df.iterrows():
    color = 'lightgreen' if row['Models'] in tree_based_models else 'blue'
    plt.scatter(row['Rank'], row['Runtime [s]'], 
                s=row['Circle_Size'], alpha=0.5, edgecolors='k', color=color)

# Add star marker for the optimal model
plt.scatter(1, 1, 
            s=200, color='gold', marker='*', edgecolors='k', label="Optimal Model")

# Annotate each model
for _, row in agg_df.iterrows():
    plt.text(row['Rank'], row['Runtime [s]'], row['Models'], fontsize=9, ha='right', va='center')

# Logarithmic scale for the Y-axis
plt.yscale('log')
plt.yticks([10**0, 10**1, 10**2, 10**3, 10**4], ['$1$', '$10^1$', '$10^2$', '$10^3$', '$10^4$'])
plt.xlabel('Average Rank (Lower is Better)', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Runtime [s] (Log Scale)', fontsize=12)
plt.title('Visualization of Average Rank vs Runtime with Frequencies', fontsize=14)

# Custom legend
legend_elements = [
    Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='w', markerfacecolor='lightgreen', markeredgecolor='k', markersize=8, label='Tree-Based Models'),
    Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='w', markerfacecolor='blue', markeredgecolor='k', markersize=8, label='Other Models'),
    Line2D([0], [0], marker='*', color='gold', markeredgecolor='k', markersize=12, label='Optimal Model')
]
plt.legend(handles=legend_elements, loc='upper right')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

Note: to isolate some changes and scatter plot dynamic adjustments with a legend, you need to handle the legend to fix the sizes plt.legend(handles=legend_elements, ...)
